# UIWebView not load

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to load a `UIWebView`, but I can't understand why doesn't work, I'm doing this:

```
Loading *load = [[Loading alloc] init];
[load searchName];
```

then Loading.h

```
@interface Loading : NSObject <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
UIWebView *myWebView;
}

- (void) searchName;
```

Loading.m

```
- (void) searchName{

myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
myWebView.delegate = self;

NSString *urlAddress = @"www.google.com";
//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)thisWebView
{
NSString *yourHTMLSourceCodeString = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];

NSLog(@"%@",yourHTMLSourceCodeString);
}
```

why never call `webViewDidFinishLoad` method?

Comment: Because you are missing the http protocol from your URL?

Comment: No i have Tried also with the http but doesn't work...

Comment: Did you try http://? Also, why are you allocating another webView? If you are using the .xib then you should attach the webView, not allocate a new one. Especially since you are never adding the webView to the frame.

Comment: Interface Builder I mean. Not .xib

Comment: @Piero: [self.view addSubview:myWebView]; and make sure your webView is initiated with frame.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your webview is not displayed is you have taken `NSObject` class and `NSObject` classes dont have an `XIB` and the way you have done is just calling your `-(void)searchName` method and is not adding it to `self.view`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you created this webview with IB? Did you connected the delegate to the webview?

1. Try to catch errors with `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` (post them if there are errors)
2. Try to set the delegate with code `[myWebView setDelegate:self];` or `self.myWebView.delegate = self;`

**Check output of delegate if nothing happend:**

```
self.myWebView.delegate = self;
NSLog(@"%@",self);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take note into what Nathan said. I am just expanding.

If you are using IB, connect the outlet. Then use [`myWebView setDelegate:self];`

Be sure to use `http://`. Http on it's own won't do anything.

Can you get other URL's to load?

Finally, I have an open source basic web browser for Cocoa that you can take a look at.

[Basic Web Browser](https://sites.google.com/site/infiniteopensyntax/basic-web-browser)